# How do I narrow a type based on generic extending keyof an union type

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to narrow this with no success.

I have two interfaces, which are merged into an union type, which is used with a generic type on a function.

My doubt is how to narrow in this case...

I tried the below, with no success

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

interface FlatWise {
  flat: Function
} 

type TypeConstrains = FlatWise | Lengthwise

function loggingIdentity<T extends keyof TypeConstrains>(arg: T): T {
//I am not able to narrow it here
  if("length" in arg) { 
  console.log(arg.length); 
  }
  return arg;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `T extends keyof TypeConstrains` and not `T extends TypeConstrains` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the `loggingIntentity` function is meant to be doing. If it is what I think, does it not make sense to have a class which stores an array and has two functions (`flattenLength()` and `flattenWidth()`)?

Comment: Hi @TomBailey.  This has no practical utility. The two interfaces could be of anything. I am just trying to understand the typing functionality of Typescript.